# How to get image URL-s from Google image search

Tags: c#, .net, image, api

I need a simple method that helps me search images @Google, and I can extract URL with. I only need the first 20 images, and I don't need to visualize it, only get urls. I need a short code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question, you should try first something by yourself, and afterwards ask again if you have any problem.

The Google Image Search API offers access through a RESTful interface, as described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_intro_fonje), on the API reference page.

You can use a class to make the request (dunno exactly which in C #) and a JSON library to parse the results.

Comment: The Web Search API has been deprecated for over 8 months now.

Comment: But still works, right? Is there any other method to access the Image Search API?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a html parser like [SimpleHTMLDomParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to return all links within the page.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```